# PHP Laravel how to use two forms in one view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a `Laravel`-app where I have two forms in one `blade`-template, which appears depending on which tab is active.

It looks like this:

```
<div data-contact-form-id="1" class="contact-form" id="contact-company">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contact.company') }}">
    // bunch of input fields here
   </form>
</div>
<div data-contact-form-id="2" class="contact-form" id="contact-private">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('contact.store') }}">
    // bunch of input fields here
   </form>
</div>
```

then my `web.php`

```
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@store')->name('contact.store');
Route::post('contact/company', 'ContactController@company')->name('contact.company');
```

but I can't submit the "company-contact" form, and when I try to do remove the slash in the route I get an error `route.store` is not defined:

```
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@store')->name('contact.store');
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@company')->name('contact.company');
```

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Comment: You can't have two routes with the same path and method. You'll have to change the route for one of them.

Comment: "i can't submit the form" What exactly do you try? Have you taken a look at the network tab of the developers console to see if the request is actually send?

Comment: You can always check the output HTML from any developer tools or `view source` link to see what the form action says and also check if there are some unclosed tags which corrupt the HTML DOM which causes the forms to seem that they are nested to the browser.

Comment: @TobiasF. I get a `500` error when I try to post to `contact/company` ....

Comment: you can't submit form with two routes

Comment: Try to change 
Route::post('contact/company', 'ContactController@company') ->name('contact.company'); 
To 
Route::post('contact.company', 'ContactController@company')->name('contact.company');

Comment: If you get a 500 error, check the logs in `storage/logs` to find out why it's throwing that error.

Comment: Seems to me that you have an error in you controller's method `company()`, or in something related to it.

Answer (score 0):

put all input fields in a single form and submit to the store route.

In controller:

Here I used the company model & some fields just for example you can replace with your model & your field name

```
public function store(Request $request){
  $post = $request->all();

  Company::create([
      'company_name' => $post['company_name']
      'company_email' => $post['company_email'],
      'company_phone' => $post['company_phone']
  ]);

   // another model for contact
   Contact::create([
     'name' => $post['name'],
     'email' => $post['email'],
     'phone' => $post['phone'],
   ]);
}
```